# Home Network with Apple AirPort and Netgear Routers Being Flooded with IGMP Messages

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, airport-extreme

This is how my home network is set up:

```
Comcast Modem ---- Netgear dual WAN (doing the DHCP)
                        |
                        |
              |-------------------|
     (((Apple AirPort)))   Netgear R6300
              |
              | (Wireless)
              |
     ((([Offending Device])))
```

Both the Apple and the Netgear routers only act as access points / "extenders" and do not provide IP addresses. The device in question (with MAC address ending in b5:ea), is closer to the Apple router and connects to it.

The device in question, after some undetermined time of being on the network, starts to flood the network with IGMP Membership Reports as seen below (I have removed the source IP address).

[IGMP Wireshark Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MS4jA.jpg)

This tends to happen with no apparent pattern. One may see it minutes, hours or days after the device is plugged in. Once the flooding starts, it will make everything on the network crawl. Nothing can be reached either in the network or to the internet.

As I understand, this message is asking the router to update its tables for multicast messages for group 224.0.0.251 to *not* be filtered from all sources (due to the lack of the source list) to its IP. If so, why is this being sent so often (almost every 100 microseconds)?

Comment: I see VLAN headers. That might be important. Please edit your question to include details of your VLAN setup.

Comment: My initial hunch is that the client is not flooding the network, but that two or more of your "routers" (technically acting as switches, not routers in this case) are misbehaving and reforwarding this multicast back onto the segment it came in on, ping-ponging it back and forth forever.

Comment: @Spiff, there is no VLAN in this setup. I don't know if the device is automatically tagging the packets with the VLAN tags. This is what I see for the tags though: <br/>`802.1Q Virtual LAN, PRI: 6, CFI: 0, ID: 1<br/>
    110. .... .... .... = Priority: Voice, < 10ms latency and jitter (6)<br/>
    ...0 .... .... .... = CFI: Canonical (0)<br/>
    .... 0000 0000 0001 = ID: 1<br/>
    Type: IPv4 (0x0800)<br/>
    Padding: 0000<br/>
    Trailer: 00000000`<br/>

Comment: Describe how you made this capture, especially how/where you tapped the network.

Comment: The capture was done using wireshark running on an imac connected to the Apple airport router.

Comment: So the was iMac wired to a LAN port of the AirPort, and you were capturing on that wired Ethernet interface?